# Getting delay when calculating size of Operating system temporary file run time in Windows 10 English Operating system?

Tags: c#, performance, file-io

I am developing a tool that involves size calculation of temporary file at run time. so I used following code to calculate size of OS temporary file.

```
filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

while(true){

    .......

UInt64 fileSize = (UInt64)(new FileInfo(filePath)).Length;

    .......

}
```

When I run this size calculation code in Windows 10 Japanese Operating system  than its take only 1 millisecond each time to calculate size.

but when i run this size calculation code  in Windows 10 English Operating system than it is taking 30 millisecond each time to calculate size.

To verify this problem in Windows 10 English Operating system I changes temporary file path to following hard coded local drive path file path

```
filePath = D:\LocalTempFilePath\Test.tmp;

while(true){

.......

UInt64 fileSize = (UInt64)(new FileInfo(filePath)).Length;

.......

}
```

then windows 10 English Operating system takes 1 millisecond only.

1.Why Windows 10 English operating system takes 30 millisecond each time to calculate size when I am using Operating system Temporary file ??

2. Is there any difference between Japanese OS temporary file and English OS Temporary file.

Any Solution for this problem.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: title of question is hard for me to understand - can it be shortened?

Comment: There is no difference in the operating system in this respect, your findings are inaccurate and there is something else which is causing the anomaly.

Comment: Any chance the "English" system just has a slower hard drive?

Comment: Some questions you need to consider: Are all these tests on identical hardware (i.e. CPU, Memory, Hard Drive)? If the hard drives are mechanical (not SSD) are they both at identical usage levels? (if one is at 10% but the other at 85%, that could affect the results). Again if the HD is mechanical, is either of them fragmented? Is the TEMP location in the same spot on the hard drives?